# How do I set a length to a sequence?

Tags: r

I'm new to coding in general and I only ask this in case I'm asked to measure "y" with 50 points for "x" to graph scatterplot of y vs x

`x <- seq(2, 5, by = 0.2)` the length would be 16 using `length(x)`

How do I make it automatically choose the "by" to fit length of 50?

(If there's a package that makes sequences more efficient than base R, that would also be helpful to know)

Comment: Try `x <- seq(2, 5,length.out = 50)`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to calculate the `by=` for any reason to fit the length, you could do:

```
from. <- 2
to. <- 5
length. <- 50
(by. <- (to. - from.)/(length.-1))
# [1] 0.06122449

seq(from=from., to=to., by=by.)
#  [1] 2.000000 2.061224 2.122449 2.183673 2.244898
#  [6] 2.306122 2.367347 2.428571 2.489796 2.551020
# [11] 2.612245 2.673469 2.734694 2.795918 2.857143
# [16] 2.918367 2.979592 3.040816 3.102041 3.163265
# [21] 3.224490 3.285714 3.346939 3.408163 3.469388
# [26] 3.530612 3.591837 3.653061 3.714286 3.775510
# [31] 3.836735 3.897959 3.959184 4.020408 4.081633
# [36] 4.142857 4.204082 4.265306 4.326531 4.387755
# [41] 4.448980 4.510204 4.571429 4.632653 4.693878
# [46] 4.755102 4.816327 4.877551 4.938776 5.000000
```

However, normally you would do `seq(2, 5,length.out=50)` as already stated in comments.

```
stopifnot(all.equal(seq(from., to., by.), seq(2, 5,length.out=50)))
```